# Installing NVidia GeForce 1070TX Graphics Card in HP OMEN-17-w250tx (Linux) without login loop issue

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am looking to procure a new laptop for my deep learning application. I am considering HP OMEN - 17-w250tx with 8GB NVidia GeForce 1070TX Graphics Card. 
I will be installing Ubuntu 14.04 in this machine. I am not sure about the support for this graphic card on Ubuntu 14.04.

1. Has anyone tried out installing NVidia GeForce 1070TX on Ubuntu 14.04 on the same or similar laptops?
2. Have anyone faced login loop issues due to the installation?
3. How to solve the login loop issue for this particular issue?
4. Request for a step by step procedure to install NVidia GeForce 1070TX on HP OMEN - 17-w250tx with Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Just curious... why would you install 14.04? Why not a newer version that has a better chance of supporting this hardware?

Comment: Thanks Heynnema. I work with some softwares that don't have ubuntu 16.04 support. 
Is the login loop issue solved in 16.04 version of ubuntu

Comment: A "login loop" can be caused by a number of things. Are you having this problem **now**, or is this a hypothetical what if? You could always boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in "Try Ubuntu" mode to try it out, and check out the Nvidia drivers from there.

Comment: I had this issue while installing NVidia GeForce 650M Graphic card on ubuntu 14.04. A few of my friend also have the same issue will installing different graphic card on ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can test this all from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB. Install the Nvidia drivers from the Ubuntu repositories, not from the Nvidia web site.

Answer (score 0):

I have the HP OMEN 17-an051ur laptop. 
When I trying to install Ubuntu v18.04; v17.10; v16.04 - they do not work correctly. 
**Only the Ubuntu v14.04 good work with this model of laptop**. You need to install all drivers (download from internet) for support video and sound hardware.
In my laptop use discreet video-card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/834642)

Comment: @ubashu This looks like an answer:  OP is responding that 14.04 is the version that works without a problem...